# OpenShift - Call external Services - Which IP is used

Tags: openshift-origin

I am currently evaluating `OpenShift` and there is a question regarding the networking of OpenShift which I wasn't able to find an answer about.

Which IP is used, if n Pod accesses an external service? 
To be more specific: Which IP would be listed in the access-log of an webserver, that is accessed by a service inside a Pod?

Is it the IP of the Pod or the Node that the Pod is running on?

Comment: Might be wrong here, but I think what you'll end up doing is creating Routes to make your POD accessible to the, and from the 'outside' world. Hence to the outside it would look like the node did the connection. Also incoming connections would hit the node, on a given port that is mapped by the Route to a given POD. Happy to be corrected, so I know if this not the case.

Comment: I think so too. Especially, after reading the following chapter in the manual(https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/architecture/additional_concepts/sdn.html):
--- snip ---
Finally, if container A connects to an external host, the traffic looks like:

eth0 (in A’s netns) → vethA → br0 → tun0 → (NAT) → eth0 (physical device) → Internet
-- snip ---
It still hope, that some actually tried it and saw the information in a log.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the IP by using dig or telnet on your master or any of your nodes. You just use the service. The service should be something like:

`<service-name>.<project-name>.svc`

It should resolve to a 10.x.x.x ip address.